# Do we have to pay insurance while on short term disability?

Tags: united-states, insurance, short-term

My wife is about to go on short term disability for 3 weeks for maternity leave. Her work is telling her that we need to keep enough money in our account to cover her insurance premiums while she is not getting a normal payroll check, is this true? I don't really know to believe them, since we have been getting different answers from her HR dept. whenever we ask about it, they don't seem to know too much about it for some reason.

Has anyone had experience with that?

Comment: Don't ask questions ask for the documents. The company and the insurance company should have worked all this out. It is more than your insurance premiums it also relates to 401K, charity, loans...

Comment: Oh ok good idea, so I'm guessing its not unheard of then if it is true.

Answer (score 3):

This depends on the details of the insurance plan the company offers, but no, that is not uncommon.

There are sometimes supplemental plans/options that you can sign up for -- at additional cost -- which will maintain payments to the medical plan, the 401(k), or other recurring deductions while you are on leave. Talk to your HR department about those; it's almost certainly too late to sign up this year but it's something you might want to consider in the future. (Personally, I haven't yet sen the need.)